# Adicionar Chip do materialize se o usuário esquecer de clicar enter

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, materialize

Eu tenho uma tela de cadastro que tem um campo de tags..
Conforme ele vai preenchendo e pressiona enter, fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vamos supor que ele cadastrou, mas esqueceu de dar enter em uma tag, por exemplo: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa tag se perderá, quando ele clicar em editar esse cadastro vai ter somente A, B e C.

Como poderia fazer para verificar isso? Quando ele clicar em cadastrar, ver se todos os elementos estão dentro de: `$('.chips').material_chip('data'));` se um não tiver, inserir.

Comment: Creio não haver possibilidade para isto, pois, como você vai inserir algo que não tem? Este chips funcionam justamente com a tecla enter para ficar registrados em data, se a pessoa digitou algo no input e esqueceu de apertar enter é como se aquele input estivesse vazio.

Comment: @LeAndrade não daria para no onBlur fazer o "enter"?

Comment: @hugocsl Cara pela breve lida na documentação **(até por que é bem pouca)** o evento padrão é o enter mesmo, e não vi métodos para se mudar isto. Acho que mesmo criando uma função com blur o chips espera-rá o enter para guardar em data.

Comment: putz... vou pesquisar mais afundo e ver se encontro algo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode fazer desta forma:

```
// evento submit do formulário
$("form").on("submit", function(){

   // pega o valor do que foi digitado e não foi incluído no chip
   var chipp = $(".chips input").val().trim();

   // se não for null
   if(chipp){
      // adiciona o chip ao array
      var obj = {};
      obj["tag"] = chipp;
      $('.chips').material_chip('data').push(obj);

      // renderiza todos os chips
      // se você só precisa da array, talvez o código abaixo não seja necessário
      $('.chips').material_chip({
         data: $('.chips').material_chip('data')
      });


   }
});
```

Exemplo sem submeter o formulário para visualização:

```js
$("form").on("submit", function(e){
   
   e.preventDefault();
   var chipp = $(".chips input").val().trim();
   
   if(chipp){
      var obj = {};
      obj["tag"] = chipp;
      $('.chips').material_chip('data').push(obj);

      $('.chips').material_chip({
         data: $('.chips').material_chip('data')
      });

      console.log($('.chips').material_chip('data'));

   }
});


$('.chips').material_chip('data');
$('.chips').material_chip();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<form method="post" action="teste2.php">
<div class="chips">
   <input name="tags" class="custom-class" placeholder="Digite as tags">
</div>
<button>OK</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Excelente resposta Sam, neste Materialize tem que ser feito tudo por fora, pq por padrão é muito mal implementado. Por exemplo, acho que deveria ir guardando no data com espaço ao invés de enter, se a pessoa der espaço e continuar digitando ele grava como um string só, tbm se as tags quebrarem o tamanho do input, não grava mais no data.